# Run system commands when logged into MySQL

Tags: mysql, windows, command-line

This is NOT about MySQL's "data directory".

When I log into MySQL on my machine (Windows 10 OS) I know that MySQL still has a "current working directory": importing a .sql file works, giving only the filename, **if** the file is located in the same directory as the one where I went

```
> mysql -u ....
```

So I wondered whether it was possible to get the CWD when actually logged into MySQL.  Then I wondered whether it might be possible to change it, i.e. to navigate somewhere else.  Then I wondered about running system (i.e. command prompt) commands generally, while still logged in to MySQL.

[Here](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/shell-commands-mysql-command-line-client/) we see a claim that you can indeed do all these things... by going something like:

```
\! ls -l
```

On my machine this doesn't work... probably because it's not a Linux OS.  I get `unknown command '\!'`...

Is there any way to do this in Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. The Windows version of the mysql command line client lacks the shell escape `\!` command.

It is an open source project :-). You or I could give them a pull request with a fix.  But then we'd have to decide whether we wanted `cmd` or `powershell` in the escaped process.

Comment: Thanks for the info.